# Timeout with SP. Would a composite index help (clustered or not)?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012. I have a table with over 10 million records.  Front end is a webform with multiple checkboxes, radiobuttons, two date textboxes (From/To), etc...

variables included in the WHERE statement of my stored procedure are:

- TIME_STAMP
- STATE
- JTYPE
- CIE
- newtech_ind
- MD_SF_IND
- FC_CD_IND
- WL_IND
- COMPLETED_IND
- INTERV
- DDINT
- DAY_OF_WEEK

Table is updated only once daily, early in the morning.  Traffic is low, it's intended for analysis purposes.

My current index is:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Summary] ON [dbo].[Summary]
(
    [TIME_STAMP] ASC,
    [STATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

TIME_STAMP is used with the "From/To" textboxes.  It's the most important field as it is used by analysts to query different intervals, ranging from a single day, to many months at once.
Currently, I'm having timeouts when people select a wide interval range using that TIME_STAMP variable (which is datetime2(0) type).

I presume my index is at fault.  Would possibly adding a composite index which would include all the variables used in my WHERE clause help ?  Is there a better way ?

Comment: You need to include the sql + create table clause + query plan + preferably also statistics io output for the query. Just a guess but it might be either key lookups, spill to temp db or sorting that's causing your issues.

Comment: This has the distinct appearance of being a search type of query? And then inside is probably a lot of where predicates similar to "AND INTERV = @INTERV or @_INTERV IS NULL"?? This is known as a catch-all query and the performance can be utterly abysmal. Check out this link for some ways to deal with this. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: @Sean Lange, the article suggest dynamic sql which I use sometime.  I that specific case I didn't.  I guess my question is really, what would be the best type of index to use to cover all these variables ? Composite ?

Comment: That article has more suggestions than just dynamic sql. If you really want some help here making your code faster you need to read to provide more details. We need to see the tables, the actual code you are running. Also it would help if you could post the actual execution plan.